# When column is null compare two columns

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm having a problem with the next query

```
select b.street_name 
from family a, address b,adress2 c 
where a.id_family=b.id_family 
  and a.id_famiy=c.id_family
```

The problem that I have is that but some ilogical reason, there are 2 tables with adresses, so when b.street address is '' or null, i would like to compare from address another field that is called cve_col which is also on address2 which contains the name of the street.

EDIT:

I've read it again and it's confussing, I need something like if b.street_name='' then c.cve_col=b.cve=col and then I could add the case on the select `select case when b.street_name='' then c.street_name end`

Comment: Join the tables in your query so you can read the fields from both.

Comment: @Renan The tables are joined, it is using an implicit join

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
select (case when b.street_name='' and b.street_name is null 
        then c.street_name end)street_name
from family a, address b,adress2 c 
where 
case when b.street_name<>'' and b.street_name is not null then a.id_family=b.id_family and a.id_famiy=c.id_family
else  c.cve_col=b.cve=col
end
```

Comment: the problem on this code is that I'm getting an error on the comparison of a.id_family=b.id_family in the '=' sign it says there's an incorrect syntax near '='

Answer (score -1):

The key is to use a case statement with an OR. see the script below...it's re-runnable in a test database.

```
drop table family
drop table [address]
drop table adress2
go

CREATE Table family (
    id_family int 
    , familyName varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [address] (
    id_family int
    , street_name varchar(50)
    )

CREATE TABLE adress2  (
    id_family int
    , cve_col varchar(50)
    )
GO

INSERT family(id_family, familyName)
SELECT 1, 'Jones'
UNION SELECT 2, 'Smith'
UNION SELECT 3, 'Brown'

INSERT [address] (id_family, street_name)
SELECT 1, 'Jones St.'
UNION SELECT 2, ''
UNION SELECT 3, NULL

INSERT adress2(id_family, cve_col)
SELECT 1, ''
UNION SELECT 2, 'smith pl.'
UNION SELECT 3, 'brown ln.'

SELECT a.familyName
    , street_name = CASE WHEN b.street_name is NULL OR b.street_name = '' THEN C.cve_col
            ELSE b.street_name
        END
FROM family a 
    INNER JOIN [address] b ON A.id_family = b.id_family
    INNER JOIN [adress2] C ON A.id_family = C.id_family
```